# dygraphs appears in the html

Tags: html, r, jupyter-notebook, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I use `dygraphs` on my website, and dygraphs is embedded in the `jupyter notebook` (ipynb) file as an input for the web HTML. However, it shows the same two dygraphs plots close to each other on the website. [image]

The code in my ipynb file is :

```
dy <- dygraph(cum_etf_re, main = "Return rate of SP500 and others") %>% 
    dyAxis("y", label = "Cum_Return") %>% 
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20) %>%
    dyLegend(width = "500")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(dy, "m.html")
display_html('<iframe src="m.html" width=100% height=450></iframe>')
```

Update 2018.1.1:

I try to fix the problem myself and did some tests. I found when I removed the code `display_html('<iframe src="m.html" width=100% height=450></iframe>')`in the ipynb file, and put the `m.html` on my terminal, the dygraph plot that appears on the center of code block would disappear. So the problem is this code. And I checked generated html file of the ipynb file, I found the related html code is as following:

```
<span class="c1">#htmlwidgets::saveWidget(dy, "m.html")</span>
display_html<span class="p">(</span><span class="s">'<iframe src="m.html" width="100%" height="450"></iframe>'</span><span class="p">)</span>
</pre></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="output_wrapper">
<div class="output">
<div class="output_area">
<div class="prompt"></div>
<div class="output_html rendered_html output_subarea ">
<iframe height="450" src="m.html" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Update 2 :

Ok, I figured out what is going on here, the `iframe` is recognized twice, once in the code block inside the parenthesis, once in the output of the function `display_html`. The problem is, how can I avoid this?

Any thoughts would be helpful!

Comment: I'm not seeing a specific question.

Comment: @42, hi, the problem of my website if that I could see two dygraph plots showing together, as in the picture I post.